# ssrs get total from a date parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a matrix report with a start date and end date parameters.

Outside the column groups, I have other columns that counts different totals.

I need another column that shows the total from the end date parameter of the month.

Example, start date = '12/1/2022' ; end date = '2/28/2023'.

I want a column to show the total in February 2023 (end date parameter).

Thank you community!

Answer (score 2):

There's really not much to go on in your question, it really needs much more detail, but you probably need something along the lines of ...

```
=SUM(
    IIF(
        YEAR(Fields!MyDateField.Value) = YEAR(Parameters!EndDate.Value) 
        AND 
        MONTH(Fields!MyDateField.Value) = MONTH(Parameters!EndDate.Value),
        Fields!myAmountColumn.Value,
        0)
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

does you parameter existe in youd dataset that you have been selected ?
and you can not just to click on the column that you want to calcule its SUM and click add total ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).